# Is something wrong with my return value?

Tags: c, function

I had to make a function that prints out all the numbers in an array (provided in 'main'), within a certain index (e.g. between 0-11, or 2-6, etc). Then the function has to return the value of the last index value.

For example, given the array

```
{8, 3, 6, 7, 9, 5, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5}
```

If I input the numbers `2` and `7`, then it should printf `{6 7 9 5 3 8}`, and then return `8. However it keeps returning`6`.

```
int index(int data[], int low, int high)
{       
    while(low <= high) {
        printf("%d\n", data[low]);
        low++;
    }

    return data[low];     
}

/* I know I could just put return[high], but i though it  
   wouldn't matter since 'low' keeps incrementing until low == high */

int main()
{       
    int activities[12] = {8, 3, 6, 7, 9, 5, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5}; 
    int low, high;
    int x;

    printf("What is the starting day?  ");
    scanf("%d", &low);
    printf("What is the ending day?  ");
    scanf("%d", &high);

    x = index(activities, low, high);
    printf("\n\nThe function returns this value: %d",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about it for a little... You loop until `low == high`, and in the loop you print `data[low]` followed by `low++`. What is the value of `low` when the loop ends? If you knew how to use a debugger you could have stepped through the code line by line in a minute and found it all out in less time it took than to write your question. :)

Comment: Your absolutely right. I should have noticed it too. I feel embarrassed now, but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

When you return `data[low]`, low is already incremented by 1. The last value of low would be `high + 1`. The while condition would fail and then come out of the loop.

So, your code should be:

```
return data[high];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the last value using the `low` variable you can simply do

```
return data[--low];
```

Because while checking the condition it fails when the value of `low` is greater than the value of `high`.

For example the if you enter low = 2 and high = 7, in the last iteration low become 8 and break the loop which now points to value 6 in activities array since activities[8] == 6

So I would suggest to simply return the value using the last index that is,

```
 return data[high];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just 
return data[high];
You incremented low to one after high so it returns that value.

Comment: This is correct, except for the (strange, and probably mistaken) situation when `high` is less than `low`. But that'd probably be undefined behaviour anyways.